# How to display selected item from ListView in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datagrid

I recently started learning WPF and c#. Sorry if the question is stupid.

I have some [Class Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h2XI.png). Which inside contains the [Class Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzjYO.png).

Information about the Client class In addition to the Account class, it is displayed in the [ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4IK3.png). Everything is good here.

There are also simple [textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFe1r.png)  that link to the selected ListView item via

`Text="{Binding ElementName=LVclientBase, Path=SelectedItem.phoneNumber}"`.
Everything is fine here too.

Now I need to create a DataGrid that will display information from the Account class for the element selected in the Listview.I made by analogy with textBox. But that doesn't work.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="isDeposit" Binding="{Binding ElementName=LVclientBase, Path=SelectedItem.accounts.isDeposit}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="accountNumber" Binding="{Binding ElementName=LVclientBase, Path=SelectedItem.accounts.accountNumber}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="balance" Binding="{Binding ElementName=LVclientBase, Path=SelectedItem.accounts.balance}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I think that there is a problem with the fact that there is a list and not a single value, but I don’t understand how to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bind ItemsSource to `accounts` collection and fix column bindings accordingly:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=LVclientBase, Path=SelectedItem.accounts}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="isDeposit" Binding="{Binding Path=isDeposit}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="accountNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=accountNumber}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="balance" Binding="{Binding Path=balance}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you. If someone needs it. To avoid duplication of columns, you also need to add AutoGenerateColumns="False" to DataGrid

Comment: @Enya Or you do not explicitly declare any Columns. The result should be the same, at least with the Headers you currently have.